# iPhone Mail Client prevent timestamp calendar linking?

Tags: iphone, html, css, ios

In my app I'm generating an email with a time stamp... The iPhone mail client is making that timestamp a link, ugly blue and an underline. How can I tell the iPhone not to do this?

```
<td style="text-align:right;color:#999999;padding-right:5px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;line-height:11px">                                                           3:54am Jul 23
</td>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a hack: put the string "am" in a `<span/>` and put an `<img/>` tag after "am" and after "Jul" pointing to a transparent GIF.

Comment: still hoping for a non-hack solution

Answer (score 1):

Can you try and display the numbers using ascii codes? My guess is that the phone then won't see it as a phone number anymore...

```
&#48; = 0
&#49; = 1
&#50; = 2
&#51; = 3
&#52; = 4
//and so on
```